# Multiple websites in IIS with native dll use 100% or core CPU

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, .net-2.0, firebird

I have an application which makes uses of firebird embedded. There are five instances of this application in IIS all in the same Application Pool.

Whenever one of the sites in the pool is stopped or recycled the other four websites will then have a thread each that uses 100% of the CPU for the core it's running on (I can't tell if it's a new thread of an existing one that jumps to 100%) . So there are four threads using 100% CPU of four cores.

I've been using Process Explorer to try and find out more. The threads all have a call stack that looks mostly like this:

```
ntoskrnl.exe!KiCpuId+0xb6
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMutexObject+0x13c0
ntoskrnl.exe!KeUpdateRunTime+0x51
ntdll.dll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa
KERNELBASE.dll!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x9a
fbembed.dll!BLOB_edit+0x3430c
fbembed.dll!BLOB_edit+0x1faa6c
fbembed.dll!BLOB_edit+0x1fb5f9
fbembed.dll!isc_dsql_execute_immediate+0x1c1
MSVCR80.dll!endthreadex+0x47
MSVCR80.dll!endthreadex+0x104
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x1a
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

This is running in IIS7 and IIS8 with .NET framework version is 2.0

Comment: Just to be sure, have each of those application instance its own copy of the Firebird Embedded server? Or do they share it?

Comment: @Guillem Vicens each website has it's own copy. As far as p/invoking a native dll in a single process goes. I am using the official firebird ADO.NET Data Provider which is wrapper for the native dll.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to ask also if they share the database. If the answer is no then they should not interact.

Comment: @Guillem Vicens each site has it's own database

Comment: What happens if you don't use embedded, but a normal Firebird server instead?

Comment: I believe that works (untested though), however I'd still like to know what the issue is with embedded.

Comment: Check these 2 firebird FAQs: [Firebird server is very slow, using 100% of system resources, etc.](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq333/) and [fb superserver running at 100%](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq312/). Maybe one of them has the clue you need

Comment: Otherwise, consider filing a bug on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET